# Why am I getting a rounded output when running this code?

Tags: java, methods, division

I am trying to have this code convert inches to feet, but whenever I try and get an output I find it is rounded down even though I am returning it as a float.

I have tried changing the code to do the modulus function + the division function, but the only gave the remainder. I am new to code so this is probably really easy just can't seem to figure it out.

``````````````````JAVA`````````````````````````````````
//this is the method that I using to output.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(calcFeetAndInchesToCentimeters(34));
}
```

//this is the method I am actually using to calculate.

```
public static float calcFeetAndInchesToCentimeters(int inches){
    if(inches >= 0){
        return inches / 12;
    }else{
        return -1;
    }
 }
```

output: 
2.0

```
I would like to have the output be when I run the code above 2.83, however,​ I am only getting the rounded down version. I am not trying to find a
```

Comment: Use one of the parameters in `return` as float: `return inches / 12.0f;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typecast inches to float and then divide.

```
public static float calcFeetAndInchesToCentimeters(int inches) {
    if (inches >= 0) {
        return ((float) inches) / 12;
    } else {
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I knew it was something simple, but right now there is just so much new info I can't remember everything.

Answer (score 1):

you can cast integer to float and then try

```
public static float calcFeetAndInchesToCentimeters(int inches){
    if(inches >= 0){
        return (float)inches / 12;
    }else{
        return -1;
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are passing an integer to the method and dividing by an `int` so the result will always be an `int`.  To fix this just change your method to:

```
    public static float calcFeetAndInchesToCentimeters(float inches){}
```